# Powershell not sourcing .profile

Tags: powershell, .profile

```
 New-SshSession -ComputerName cagent01 
 $A= Invoke-SshCommand -InvokeOnAll -Quiet -Command '~/.bash_profile'
 $B= Invoke-SshCommand -InvokeOnAll -Quiet -Command '~/.bashrc'
 $Result = Invoke-SshCommand -InvokeOnAll -Quiet -Command './start'
 $Ora = Invoke-SshCommand -InvokeOnAll -Quiet -Command 'echo $ORACLE_HOME'
 write-host "Oracle home is $Ora"
 Remove-SshSession -RemoveAll
```

i use PowerShell v3. This script isn't sourcing my .profile.
I don't see $Ora printing any value.

When I manually log into the server to do echo $PATH, it includes the ORACLE path

echo $PATH

/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/data/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/d‌​bhome_1/bin:/home/HEALTHLANGUAGE/scmbuild/bin:/home/db2inst1/sqllib/bin:/home/db2‌​inst1/sqllib/adm:/home/db2inst1/sqllib/misc

The .bash_profile does export the PATH variable. 
export PATH

When I run a bamboo plan on this agent, it says ORACLE_HOME is not set. Manually loggin into the server sources the path correctly, but i want to do it using the script.

Can someone please help me with a work around? Or is it not possible to do this using PowerShell for Linux servers?

Comment: Are you sure those commands are executing within the same remote shell session? I wouldn't assume that by default. Do you get the output you expect if you string them all together in one command? `. ~/.bash_profile; . ~/.bashrc; echo "$ORACLE_HOME"`?

Comment: Tried this but no good.
$A= Invoke-SshCommand -InvokeOnAll -Quiet -Command '. ~/.bash_profile; . ~/.bashrc; echo "$ORACLE_HOME" '

Comment: Did you get any output from that? Is `$ORACLE_HOME` set in one of those files?

Comment: I tried this $Z = Invoke-SshCommand -InvokeOnAll -Quiet -Command 'echo $PATH' and get the desired output "Path is /usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin"
it is just the ORACLE_HOME which is not getting sourced

Comment: That path is almost certainly being set by the system shell init files and not your user shell init files. But loading the user shell init files manually (as in my previous command) should work correctly.

Comment: Ok this is how my .bash_profile looks like
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
DB2INSTANCE=db2inst1
INSTHOME=/home/db2inst1
export DB2INSTANCE
export INSTHOME
. $INSTHOME/sqllib/db2profile
      I added this and the ORALCE_HOME is getting displayed now...
ORACLE_HOME=/data/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1
export ORACLE_HOME

Comment: It sources the ORACLE_HOME automatically when I  manually log in to that server. My question is why cannot I do the same using the script? 
This is a virtual server and the next time they revert snapshot there its gonna alter the .profile. Is there a way to do it without altering the .profile file?

Comment: Get them to include that in the snapshot configuration? You can set that variable anywhere you want. But if you need it in the shell init files on the server and it isn't in the snapshot configuration then you are going to need to add it back each time.

Comment: Alright, ill get a way to create a new snapshot with this configuration. Thank you!!

Comment: I manually logged into the server and echoed the path variable to see that the ORACLE_HOME is included in the PATH and the .bash_Profile does export the PATH variable. 
 echo $PATH
/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/data/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin:/home/HEALTHLANGUAGE/scmbuild/bin:/home/db2inst1/sqllib/bin:/home/db2inst1/sqllib/adm:/home/db2inst1/sqllib/misc

So including the ORACLE_HOME again to the .profile is a duplicating effort

Comment: You need to set the variable in the correct file for the type of shell sessions you need to have it available in. `.profile`/`.bash_profile` is for login shells, `.bashrc` is for interactive non-login shells.

Comment: I sourced the /etc/profile in my .bashrc and incorporated that change to the new snapshot. It works like a charm now. Thank you so much for all the valuable inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sourced the /etc/profile in my .bashrc and incorporated that change to the new snapshot. It works like a charm now. Thank you so much for all the valuable inputs